What is Dickson's lemma?
Dickson's lemma states that, for a fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}^+$, every set of $k$
-tuples of natural numbers has finitely many elements that are minimal with respect to the product order induced on $\mathbb{N}^k$
from the integers.
How to understand Dickson's lemma easily with an example?

This sounds like a question of pure mathematics.  Is there some reason it needs to be answered from a computer science perspective?  If not, it doesn't seem on-topic here (but might possibly be ok on Math.SE, with some revision).

What research have you done?  Our mission is to build an archive of knowledge that will add to what is available on the Internet, so we expect you to consult standard resources.  See, e.g., https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.  It seems there is already an example in the Wikipedia article on Dickson's lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_lemma.  And I don't understand what prevents you from working through an example by yourself.
